# PHP: number of loop rounds in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

A basic php question from a non-professional coder. I have a snippet of code with a loop defined as follows:

```
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {// do sth
```

I need the number of 'loop rounds' that definition produces, and I need it before entering the loop, so I can't just name a counter and look at it when the loop's finished.

I know there must be some really simple line of code that gives me the total number of those $attachments, but I just don't know php enough to know that line by heart. Could someone help me a bit with this simple problem, please?

Comment: you can use count($attachments).

Comment: have you consider doing this in `for loop` ? you'll meet `count()`

Comment: count() did the trick! Thanks Suresh! I knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just want the number of elements in `$attachments`:

```
echo count($attachments);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [count()](https://www.php.net/count) function of php to get the length of objects.

```
count($attachments)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Since I can only vote for one right answer, it'll have to be George's this time for being a bit quicker. +1 though.